Number of arbitrary bracket strings (with n open brackets) which turns into correct ones when adding k closing brackets
There are sequences (strings) of brackets containing exactly $n$ opening brackets. How many of them turn into correct bracket sequences (i.e. with matching brackets) when adding $k$ closing brackets at the end?
Let's denote the number we seek as $A(n,k)$. The most I can do is deduce that it seems that
$$
C_n = A(n, 1) + A(n,2) + \dotsb + A(n, n)
$$
(Where $C_n$ is the $n$-th Catalan number)
(This is a study course problem to enhance understanding of Catalan numbers, recursion and generating functions. I am struggling with it.)

Remark. Please add context and motivation to the question or else it will get close votes as per MSE guidelines, which discourage isolated problem statements.

This is a study course problem to enhance understanding of Catalan numbers, recursion and generating functions. I am struggling with it.

Please move the comment into the question and delete comment. Also, add to the question your computations so far.

It is not clear whether your arbitrary string has length $n$ or some other length, but contains $n$ opening brackets, There is a conflict between the title and the first line.

Updated the title

We are to consider such sequences with $n$ open brackets that turn into correct/matching ones after adding exactly $k$ closing brackets (and nothing else, just one closing bracket after another) at the end. So they should necessarily contain exactly $n-k$ closing brackets.

Counting all matched strings we get the recurrence with
$C_0=1$ and $C_1=0$
$$C_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} C_k C_{n-2-k}.$$
For the  generating function multiply by  $z^n$ and sum
over $n\ge 2$ to get
$$C(z)-1 = \sum_{n\ge 2} z^n [z^{n-2}] C(z)^2
\\ = z^2 \sum_{n\ge 2} z^{n-2} [z^{n-2}] C(z)^2
= z^2 C(z)^2.$$
We see this is an even function and introduce $F(z)$ so
that  $[z^{2n}] C(z)  =  [z^n] F(z).$  It follows  that
$F(z)$  has functional  equation $(F(z)-1)/F(z)^2  = z$
and solving we have
$$F(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}.$$
Marking the  initial sequence of open  parentheses with
the variable $v$ we find with $Q_0=1$ and $Q_1=0$
$$Q_n = v \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} Q_k C_{n-2-k}.$$
We get in terms of generating functions
$$Q(z)-1 = v \sum_{n\ge 2} z^n [z^{n-2}] Q(z) C(z)
\\ = v z^2 \sum_{n\ge 2} z^{n-2} [z^{n-2}] Q(z) C(z)
= v z^2 Q(z) C(z).$$
This means that
$$Q(z) = \frac{1}{1-vz^2 C(z)}.$$
We also see that $Q(z)$  is even in $z$ and introducing
$R(z)$ so that $[z^{2n}] Q(z) = [z^n] R(z)$ we get
$$R(z) = \frac{1}{1-vz F(z)}.$$
Extracting the  opening segment of length  $q$ (i.e. by
bijection the trailing $q$ closing parentheses) we thus
require
$$[z^n] z^q F(z)^q = [z^{n-q}] F(z)^q 
= \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^{n-q+1}} F(z)^q.$$
Now put $z  F(z) = w$ so  that $z = w (1-w)$  and $dz =
(1-2w) \; dw$ to get
$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1} (1-w)^{n+1}} w^q (1-2w).$$
Extract the coefficient for a result of
$${2n-q\choose n} - 2 {2n-q-1\choose n}.$$
This is OEIS A033184 and in
terms  of  paths  it   counts  exactly  the  admissible
parenthesisations  of a  string of  length $2n$  having
first  peak  (or  last,  by symmetry)  of  height  $q$,
i.e. $q$ leading or trailing open / closed parentheses.
Now adjusting our variables to the problem statement we
see that  the prefix that  is matched to the  string of
length   $k$   of   closing  parentheses   has   length
$n+n-k=2n-k$,  consisting of  the $n$  open parentheses
and the missing $n-k$  closing parentheses, for a total
length of $2n.$ As long as last peak height is at least
$k$  and  at  most  $n$ that  forces  all  $n$  opening
parentheses  into the  prefix,  yielding an  admissible
path. We get the sum
$$\sum_{q=k}^n {2n-q\choose n}
- 2\sum_{q=k}^n {2n-q-1\choose n}.$$
Evaluating the first one we get
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {2n-k-q\choose n}
= [z^n] (1+z)^{2n-k} \sum_{q=0}^{n-k} (1+z)^{-q}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{2n-k}
\frac{1-1/(1+z)^{n-k+1}}{1-1/(1+z)}
\\ = [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^{2n-k+1} (1-1/(1+z)^{n-k+1})
\\ = {2n-k+1\choose n+1}.$$
Repeat for the second one to obtain
$${2n-k\choose n+1}.$$
Collecting everything,
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{2n-k+1\choose n+1} - 2{2n-k\choose n+1}.}$$
We can  clarify the interpretation of  the problem that
is used here by some Maple code which should illustrate
the  setup  and  the  assumptions. We  have  mixed  the
concept  of  paths with  that  of  strings of  balanced
parentheses in the above  but this bijection is trivial
and follows, literally, by inspection.

with(combinat);

ADMIT :=
proc(DL)
option remember;
local len, pos;

    len := nops(DL);
    if len = 0 then return true fi;
    if type(len, `odd`) then return false fi;

    if DL[1] = 0 then
        for pos from 2 to len by 2 do
            if DL[pos] = 1 then
                if ADMIT(DL[2..pos-1])
                and ADMIT(DL[pos+1..len])
                then return true;
                fi;
            fi;
        od;
    fi;

    return false;
end;

ENUM :=
proc(n,k)
option remember;
local d, res, q, prefl,comb;

    res := 0;

    prefl := 2*n-k;
    comb := firstcomb(prefl, n);

    while type(comb, `set`) do
        d := [seq(`if`(q in comb, 0, 1), q=1..prefl)];
        d := [op(d), 1$k];
        if ADMIT(d) then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;

        comb := nextcomb(comb, prefl);
    od;

    res;
end;

X :=
proc(n,k)
    local q;
    add(binomial(2*n-q, n), q=k..n)
    - 2*add(binomial(2*n-q-1, n), q=k..n);
end;

XX :=
proc(n,k)
    binomial(2*n-k+1,n+1)-2*binomial(2*n-k,n+1);
end;


Very nice answer. (+1)
